# Get the dsata in knockout nested foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have this code,

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <!-- ko foreach:cols -->
    <td data-bind="html: $data "></td>
    <!-- /ko -->
</tr>
<!-- ko foreach:cells -->
<tr>
    <td data-bind="html: $index()+1 "></td>
    <!-- ko foreach: $data -->
    <td data-bind="html: '<div>' + $data[0] + '</div>' ,
         style:{ backgroundColor: '#' + $data[1] , color: '#' + $data[2] },
         attr:{id: $parent.cols()[$parent.$index()+1]}"></td>
    <!-- /ko -->
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

I have an example of cols.

```
self.cols(["A","B","C","D"]);
```

The error is,

```
$parent.cols is not a function
```

I think the problem is the attr binding in the last td markup. I also tried $root.cols()[$parent.$index()+1],$component.cols()[$parent.$index()+1], and $data.cols()[$parent.$index()+1] but still failed.

I need to make the td with id of something like, "B4", where "B" is from self.cols(). Then the "4" is from the index of tr markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a row or column nr at any level, you can do three things:

- Use the binding context to determine the position. I.e. `$parents` and `$index`.
- Embed the row and column numbers when constructing the viewmodels.
- Compute the row and column numbers in your viewmodels by storing references between parents and children.

Since you only need the columns and rows in your view, I think going with the first one (like you did) is the best approach. If, in the future, you want to be able to get a cell's column and row number without rendering it in a view, you'll need something like this computed, placed in your table's viewmodel:

```
self.getCellRowAndColumn = function(cell) {
  var colIndex = -1;
  var rowIndex = self.rows().findIndex(function(row) {
    colIndex = row.cells().indexOf(cell);
    return colIndex !== -1;
  });

  return { row: rowIndex, col: cellIndex };
};
```

This would allow you to add a computed property to each cell that wraps this method. You could then swap around cells and rows and everything would stay up to date.

---

Some more general advice:

I'd strongly advice to create an extra, readable layer between your view and your model. Any colleagues, or even *future-John-Arellano*, will have trouble digging through data-binds like `$data[0]`, `foreach: $data`, etc.

For a table, there's this natural sub-division of :

- `TableViewModel` that holds *rows* and *columns*
- `RowViewModel` that has a *row index* and an array of cells
- `CellViewModel` that has contents and styling, a *row index* and a *column index*.

```js
var COL_NAMES = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; // support up to 26 columns

var CellViewModel = function(cellData) {
  // Model properties mapping
  this.content = ko.observable(cellData[0]);
  this.backgroundColor = ko.observable(cellData[1]);
  this.textColor = ko.observable(cellData[2]);
  
  // Extra viewmodel props
  this.styleAttr = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return {
      backgroundColor: "#" + this.backgroundColor(),
      color: "#" + this.textColor(),
    };
  }, this);
};

CellViewModel.create = function(cellData) {
  return new CellViewModel(cellData);
};

CellViewModel.prototype.getId = function(col, row) {
  return "cell" + (row() + 1) + COL_NAMES[col()];
};

var RowViewModel = function(rowCellData) {
  this.cells = ko.observableArray(rowCellData.map(CellViewModel.create));
};

RowViewModel.create = function (rowCellData) {
  return new RowViewModel(rowCellData);
};

var TableViewModel = function(allCellData) {
  this.rows = ko.observableArray(allCellData.map(RowViewModel.create));
  
  this.cols = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    // Find row with max. cells
    var colCount = this.rows().reduce(function(max, cur) {
        return Math.max(max, cur.cells().length);
    }, 0);
    
    return COL_NAMES
      .substring(0, colCount)
      .split("");
    
  }, this);
};

// Test data
var testCellData = [
  // row 1
  [
    // col A
    [
      "Test cell 1A", // html content
      "0000FF", // background color
      "FF0000" // text color
    ],
    // col B
    [
      "Test cell 1B", // html content
      "FF0000", // background color
      "0000FF" // text color
    ]
  ],
  // row 2
  [
    // col A
    [
      "Test cell 2A", // html content
      "00FF00", // background color
      "FF0000" // text color
    ],
    // col B
    [
      "Test cell 2B", // html content
      "0000FF", // background color
      "FF0000" // text color
    ]
  ]
];

ko.applyBindings(new TableViewModel(testCellData));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th></th>
    <!-- ko foreach: cols -->
    <th data-bind="text: $data "></th>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- ko foreach: rows -->
      <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: $index() + 1"></td>
        <!-- ko foreach: cells -->
        <td data-bind="html: content,
                       style: styleAttr,
                       attr: { id: getId($index, $parentContext.$index) }"></td>
        <!-- /ko -->
      </tr>    
    <!-- /ko -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I already solved this problem using,

```
<td data-bind="html: '<div>' + $data[0] + '</div>' , style:{ backgroundColor: '#' + $data[1] , color: '#' + $data[2] }, attr:{id: $parents[1].cols()[$index()] + ($parentContext.$index()+1)}"></td>
```